# Recover code modules from corrupt vba pptm file

Tags: vba, powerpoint, corrupt

I opened my .pptm ppt vba macro source file for editing, it showed this dialog a few times.

[image]

once I open alt+F11 to VBA editor, it has all the forms but the underlying code is not opening, also the modules are unresponsive.

[image]

Can anybody suggest a way to recover code/modules from this corrupt file. I have the latest .ppam addin output,  I can share the corrupted .pptm file if there is way to attach here. Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: Are you able to see the modules, forms code?

Comment: no code are visible, only the forms ui is seen and but not codes

Comment: Try exporting them and see if it works. Being in VBE (Project Explorere), right klick on a modul/form and choose `Export File...`. If the export is allowed, you may try importing them (one by one) in another file and try opening...

Comment: I tried to export and import forms, only the form ui gets added, no underlying code on the forms. Also the modules doesn't get exported

Comment: I am afraid that the code itself has bee lost... Did you develop the add-in in discussion? If yes, don't you have a previous version? You should keep backup for previous versions... If not, you should ask the one developing it to send another copy. Now I will leave my office. If you send the file on my personal mail (in my profile) I can look at it after some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: >> "I have the latest .ppam addin output"  Does the PPAM behave as expected when you load it? If so, Go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\PowerPoint\Options
Replace xx.0 with your PPT version: 16.0 for 2016/2019/365, 15.0 for 2013, 14.0 for 2010 etc.
12.0 is 2007.  There's no 13.0; MS is apparently superstitious)

Rightclick Options and choose New, DWORD Value
Name it: DebugAddins
Doubleclick it and change its value to 1
Close Regedit.  
Now you'll be able to open/edit/export the modules/forms/classes from the PPA/PPAM, or copy/paste them from the add-in to a new PPTM project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tossing this in as an answer as well as the comment. Better formatting!

Make sure PowerPoint is NOT running, then open REGEDIT.

Go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\PowerPoint\Options
*Replace xx.0 with your PPT version: 16.0 for 2016/2019/365, 15.0 for 2013, 14.0 for 2010 etc.
12.0 is 2007.  There's no 13.0; MS is apparently superstitious.*

Rightclick Options and choose New, DWORD Value
Name it: DebugAddins
Doubleclick it and change its value to 1
Close Regedit.

Start PowerPoint and open the VBA IDE.

All of your installed VBA addins will appear as projects that you can open and edit, so long as they're not password protected (and if you know the password, you're good to go).

Note that you cannot SAVE your edited code. You'll need to copy/paste it back into a PPT/PPTM file and save that, or export the modules you've edited and import them into the original PPT/PPTM.

You can generally have both the source PPT/PPTM and the addin code loaded in the IDE; just be sure you stay aware of which is which.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve. I have exported the forms and codes from the addin and added to my pptm source file. Could you please enlighten why this may happen, so that I can avoid it in future.

Comment: @Jegan It's hard (maybe impossible) to say why it might happen, but if it happens again, especially if it's reproducible, there may be a way to pin it down. It's a very good idea to keep backups of your PPTMs as you modify them; for example, whenever you open one to edit it, you might save it to a new name that includes the current date.